# Install a vimball from the command line

Tags: command-line, installation, vim

As [this post points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033078/how-to-install-a-vimball-plugin-with-vba-extension) you can install Vimballs using the normal:

```
vim somevimball.vba
:so %
:q
```

But if you want to install a from the command line how do you do it? I ran a 'man vim' and it seems like the best "from source install" option was the '-S' option so I tried to install haskellmode with it:

```
wget 'http://projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/vimfiles/haskellmode-20090430.vba'
vim -S haskellmode-20090430.vba
```

and that failed to work. It gave me the following error:

> Error detected while processing function vimball#Vimball:
>   line   10:
>   (Vimball) The current file does not appear to be a Vimball!
>   press ENTER or type command to continue

It should be noted that using the first method I was able to successfully install the vimball. I have tried the second method on a few other vimballs and it has failed every time. Is there a way to install a vimball from the command line? It seems like a useful sort of task.

Oh, and I am running the following version of vim:

```
Version: 2:7.2.330-1ubuntu3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use one of the following commands:

```
vim -c 'so %' -c 'q' somevimball.vba
```

or:

```
vim -c 'so % | q' somevimball.vba
```

For more information, see:

```
:help -c
:help :bar
```

Comment: How would the command look like if I'd have been running Windows, not Linux?

Comment: @colemik, maybe you can try to use "" instead of '', but it should work the same basically

Answer (score 0):

Having seen this solution I decided to hide the messiness in a script that always should have existed, vim-install: http://github.com/robertmassaioli/vim-install