# How do I use tcomment (vim's plugin) and how do can I say it is installed?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

So I decided I should learn how to comment and uncomment code in a fancy way. So I tried vim plugin tcomment. I [googled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033078/how-to-install-a-vimball-plugin-with-vba-extension) that I needed to open the vba file I downloaded with vim and type

```
:source %
```

I google around but I am still not sure how to run the plugin. What do I type in in normal mode to toggle comments? Just simple one line comments. I cannot figure it out. I am convinced I installed the plugin right, but how can I make sure?

Comment: I would recommend looking at pathogen or vundle for installing vim plugins. Vimball is an outdated method (although it works uninstalling is a bigger hassle). But to check if it is installed you can run `:scriptnames`. You should see a line that ends in `tcomment.vim` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, vundle seems to work nice (even though I am not sure why I have to manually edit .vimrc file to install plugin, it would be nice if it were automated too).

Comment: If you use pathogen to install plugins then you don't have to modify your vimrc everytime you install a plugin. You just have to put them in the bundle directory and you're done.

Comment: Hm, but I need to do it with vundle, as per this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vundle-to-manage-vim-plugins-on-a-linux-vps no? (Well, if I want it to auto-load, which is generally the case, I guess)

Comment: @sup how were you able to install tcomment with pathogen? I tried cloning the repo into ~/.vim/bundle and restarting vim: no dice.

Comment: @webdevguy I used vundle and that worked (I do not remember how at all), I cannot help you with pathogen, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure you have installed the plugin you can run `:scriptnames`. This will list all enabled plugins and scripts (you are looking for `tcomment.vim`).

The commands for `tComment` are the following:

```
gc{motion}   :: Toggle comments (for small comments within one line 
                the &filetype_inline style will be used, if 
                defined)
gcc          :: Toggle comment for the current line
gC{motion}   :: Comment region
gCc          :: Comment the current line
```

More info [here](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tComment)

And the full documentation is [here](https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim/blob/master/doc/tcomment.txt)

Comment: Ok, thanks, so the problem was tha tcomment somehow was not installed. Now it is installed and I just need to type "gcc" to toggle comments.